# Foundation 4 - Sections- Centering Tabs

Tags: zurb-foundation

**Problem:** Attempting to Create 6 centered tabs in a row, however because I can't keep all 6 tabs on the same row. It does center the tabs, however pushes 2 of the tabs one line below and leaves an extra empty cell on the first line.

I tried using small-centered and made no difference.

**Version:** Foundation 4

**Browser:** Chrome - Latest

**Code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 large-centered  columns">
        <div class="section-container horizontal-nav" data-section="horizontal-nav" >
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></p>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></p>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></p>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></p>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title"><a href="#">Tab 5</a></p >
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title"><a href="#">Tab 6</a></p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Foundation 4 out of the box. By using `large-centered`, you are just centering the div containing the tabs and not the tabs themselves. The tabs will always align left.

The functionality you are looking for is available in button groups. For example `button-group even-6` will fill the entire space. Maybe it is possible to use jQuery to use a button group instead or to take a look at the JavaScript source and see how Zurb is resizing those elements and apply it to your section / tabs.

Comment: Ya that's what I am slowly doing now is looking at the source. Otherwise just keep the left alignment. If I come with a solution I will post it. Surprised no easier way to align those out of the box.